# Artin's Primitive root conjecture and Primality Statistics

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I am reading a survey on "Artin's Primitive root Conjecture" and I am  having a hard time understanding some statements made by the author.

1. The author states that, The prime number theorem in the form $$\pi(x) := \#\{p\le x\} \sim Li(x), x \rightarrow \infty $$ suggests that the probability that a number is prime is $\frac{1}{\log(n)}$. I think this probability arrives from $\frac{Li(x)}{x}$. But, I guess the statement should have been *probability that a number **not greater than n** is a prime is $\frac{1}{\log(x)}$. Kindly, explain this
2. Next, the author states that We expect $\displaystyle \sum_{2\le n\le x }\frac{1}{\log(n)} \le x $ and asymptotically this is equal to $Li(x)$. Thus from both $n$ and $4n+1$ to be prime and $n \equiv 2 (\text{ mod } 5)$ we expect a probability of $$\frac{1}{5\log^2(n)}$$ Assuming independence of these three events.  The author further claims that since these three events are not independent we have to correct by some positive constant $c$ and hence that up to $x$ there are atleast $\displaystyle \frac{cx}{\log^2(x)}$ ( note that $\displaystyle \sum_{2 \le n \le x} \frac{1}{\log^2 n} \sim \frac{x}{\log^2(x)})$ primes $p$ such that $10$ is a primitive root mod $p$. Hence, we expect there are infinitely many primes $p$ having $10$ as a primitive root mod $p$.

I have no idea how the author arrived at this statement and I am not able to find any relevant resource to understand the claim made by the author.

Reference: [Artin's primitive root conjecture, a survey -
Pieter Moree,](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0412262.pdf)

Comment: Are you clear that these are supposed to be heuristic arguments, not rigorous ones?

Comment: How did the author come up with these heuristic arguments. I mean if anyone had to come up with those arguments then how do you expect to proceed.

Comment: This paper looks as though it may have an accessible introduction to the ideas involved. (The density of primes of about size $x$ and the assumption of independence) https://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/chance_news/for_chance_news/Riemann/cramer.pdf

Comment: Initially, I thought your inference in Q1 was wrong, because you ignored Bayes Theorem.  In fact, I even posted an answer to that effect.  Then I realized that I was mistaken: just because you avoided Bayes Theorem didn't mean that your (alternate) reasoning was either invalid or inaccurate.  Therefore, I deleted my answer.

Comment: Under the random model, we pretend that "$n$ is prime" is a random event. Each integer $n \geqslant 2$ gets its own random variable $X_n$, whose value is $1$ with probability $p_n$ and $0$ with probability $1-p_n$. Then $X_n = 1$ indicates that $n$ is prime. The expected number of primes $\leqslant x$ is $$\sum_{2 \leqslant n \leqslant x} p_n\,.$$ Since $$\operatorname{Li}(x) < \sum_{2 \leqslant n \leqslant x} \frac{1}{\log n} < \operatorname{Li}(x) + \frac{1}{\log 2}$$ for $x \geqslant 2$, the choice $p_n = \frac{1}{\log n}$ (for $n > 2$) matches the PNT well.

Comment: If we choose a random number , lets say in the range $[10^{300},10^{300}+10^{20}]$ (so a long interval and numbers much larger than the length of the interval) , the chance to get a prime is approaimately $\frac{1}{\ln(10^{300})}$ . So, it is not a random number below $n$ we have to take but a random number "near" $n$.. In fact the probability is then about $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$

Comment: Of course, by ruling out some small prime factors, the chance to get a prime increases.